# Build WPF Application with Docker

Tags: c#, wpf, docker

I am new to Docker and I am trying to build a WPF application using Docker.

The WPF application runs on .NET Framework 4.8.

This is the contents of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 as base
WORKDIR /
COPY . ./
RUN nuget restore
RUN msbuild /t:Restore ./ProjectName.csproj
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release ./ProjectName.csproj
```

And im using

```
docker build -f Dockerfile . --no-cache
```

to build.

Everything runs fine until the last row when it errors out and I get this error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MSTSCLib' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm guessing there is some problem with the reference to MSTSClib, but I cant figure out how to solve it.

I've tried the following:

- Changing "copy local"
- Changing "Embed Interop Types"

Comment: Prolly COM library is needed to build interop library ... If I'm right you may: build normally on your PC, remove COM dependency and add dependency to generated MSTSClib interop. This dll should be "part of the source" (fx copy it from /bin/Release to /dlls and then add it as references - also check twice if they are relative in project file/it's XML/)

Comment: Thanks, that actually solved that problem! 

Now I've got a new error when running the same docker build command: 
 `'LoginWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Show' and no accessible extension method 'Show' accepting a first argument of type 'LoginWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Same error is repeated with every property and method called on every window.

Comment: what is LoginWindow ? is that a part of MSTSClib  or it's yours? If it's yours seems like compiler has problem with compiling XAML

Comment: Oh, that's my window, sorry for confusion :)

Comment: Do you have base class in your `*.xaml.cs` ? of course it's partial class and `*.g.cs` (normally generated from XAML) has base class but maybe its not generated yet ... also is your project is "old" or "sdk style" ?

Comment: Yes, I have it. I am using a Nuget called "MahApp.Metro" for styling of the windows. It's "old", i guess :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I really have no idea why this worked, but it did:

- Firstly I did as @Selvin told me to

> build normally on your PC, remove COM dependency and add dependency to generated MSTSClib interop. This dll should be "part of the source" (fx copy it from /bin/Release to /dlls and then add it as references - also check twice if they are relative in project file/it's XML/)

- Then i Removed the fifth line `RUN msbuild /t:Restore ./ProjectName.csproj` from my Dockerfile, and it just worked!